# How to launch Webview in Background or load a URL in Background?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-webview, background-service

I'm working on making a service of an app that loads a JavaScript enabled website in the background thread. I have tried using AsyncTask but cannot make it and as soon as I start it the App fails and stops and I have tried with WINDOW MANAGER which show that its a depriciated API. Can anyone help me in loading a webpage in background or give any code?

Comment: What is not understandable to You? Where do You stuck? Provide Your example code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

WebView is a UI widget. You must manipulate it in the UI thread.
You could perform network-related operations in a background thread (AsyncTask) but any update to a UI widget must occur in the main thread.

Also, note that the WebView in itself, knows to perform its tasks asynchronously. You should not need to load its URL request from an async task.

Comment: I'll give a try and let you know